# Java - Generate Random Password with special characters

Tags: java

Hi I would like to pick 2 random character from each String mentioned below.

```
    String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String NUMS = "1234567890";
    String SPEC = "@#$%^&+=";
```

Eg. Expected - cdAB43#-

I tried below but didn't worked.

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * chars.length());
        pass.append(chars.charAt(index));
        index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * NUMS.length());
        pass.append(NUMS.charAt(index));
        index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * SPEC.length());
        pass.append(SPEC.charAt(index));

        String password = pass.toString();
        return password;
```

Output-

```
VNVLZt5#
```

Any help would appreciate.

Comment: Please expand upon "didn't worked".

Comment: For starters, you're only selecting from 3 of the 4 character sets, and you're only doing it once for each, not twice.

Comment: Too tired to write a detailed answer, this should give you an idea: https://ideone.com/MtSwUc

Comment: Please make sure your question includes the output you are seeing, including any stack traces, so that help can be provided.

Comment: have added the output

Comment: Not really important, but why are you using `rnd.nextFloat() * chars.length()` instead of `rnd.nextInt(chars.length())`? No need to cast then.

Comment: It is not possible for code you have included to produce such output. You're appending 3 characters only and the output has 8. Unless you start with an unempty `pass` variable.

Comment: random isn't safe by theway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inferred from your question that you wanted to pick 2 random characters from each set of characters but instead you only picked 1. Moreover I used `nextInt` instead `nextFloat` because I think that its more readable, and I think you were using `List` or a `StringBuffer` so I removed it because its unnecessary here (it can be done with `String` only). The final result looks like this:

```
static String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
static String CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
static String NUMS = "1234567890";
static String SPEC = "@#$%^&+=";


public static String passwordGenerator() {
    int index;
    String pass = "";
    Random rnd = new Random();

    // 2 random chars from 'chars'
    index = rnd.nextInt(chars.length());
    pass += chars.charAt(index);
    index = rnd.nextInt(chars.length());
    pass += chars.charAt(index);

    // 2 random chars from 'CHARS'
    index = rnd.nextInt(CHARS.length());
    pass += CHARS.charAt(index);
    index = rnd.nextInt(CHARS.length());
    pass += CHARS.charAt(index);

    // 2 random chars from 'NUMS'
    index = rnd.nextInt(NUMS.length());
    pass += NUMS.charAt(index);
    index = rnd.nextInt(NUMS.length());
    pass += NUMS.charAt(index);

    // 2 random chars from 'SPEC'
    index = rnd.nextInt(SPEC.length());
    pass += SPEC.charAt(index);
    index = rnd.nextInt(SPEC.length());
    pass += SPEC.charAt(index);

    return pass;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick:

```
private String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
private String CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private String NUMS = "1234567890";
private String SPEC = "@#$%^&+=";
private Random rnd = new Random();

private String getTwoFrom(String src) {
    int index1 = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * src.length()),
            index2 = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * src.length());
    return "" + src.charAt(index1) + src.charAt(index2);
}

public String createPassword() {
    return getTwoFrom(chars) + getTwoFrom(CHARS) + getTwoFrom(NUMS) + getTwoFrom(SPEC);
}
```

Comment: Not really important, but why are you using `rnd.nextFloat() * src.length()` instead of `rnd.nextInt(src.length())`? No need to cast then

Answer (score 1):

Generating random username or password of a user defined length with at least 1 upper Case, 1 lower Case and 1 number. You may also add special character if you like.

```
    String ALPHABETIC_UPPERCASE_SYMBOLS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String ALPHABETIC_LOWERCASE_SYMBOLS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String NUMERIC_SYMBOLS = "0123456789";

    String ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPECIAL_SYMBOLS =
            ALPHABETIC_UPPERCASE_SYMBOLS +
                    ALPHABETIC_LOWERCASE_SYMBOLS +
                    NUMERIC_SYMBOLS;


    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>(length);
    boolean hasUpper = false;
    boolean hasLower = false;
    boolean hasNumber = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Make sure we have at least one upper, lower, and number
        // Then, fill randomly from set containing all characters.
        if (!hasUpper) {
            chars.add(ALPHABETIC_UPPERCASE_SYMBOLS.charAt(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, ALPHABETIC_UPPERCASE_SYMBOLS.length())));
            hasUpper = true;
        } else if (!hasLower) {
            chars.add(ALPHABETIC_LOWERCASE_SYMBOLS.charAt(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, ALPHABETIC_LOWERCASE_SYMBOLS.length())));
            hasLower = true;
        } else if (!hasNumber) {
            chars.add(NUMERIC_SYMBOLS.charAt(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, NUMERIC_SYMBOLS.length())));
            hasNumber = true;
        } else {
            chars.add(ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPECIAL_SYMBOLS.charAt(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPECIAL_SYMBOLS.length())));
        }
    }

    // Shuffle characters to mix up the first 4 characters
    Collections.shuffle(chars);

    return StringUtils.join(chars, "");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.util.Random;

public class Solution {
    public static String twoRandChars(String src) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int index1 = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * src.length());
        int index2 = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * src.length());
        return "" + src.charAt(index1) + src.charAt(index2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String NUMS = "1234567890";
        String SPEC = "@#$%^&+=";

        String pass = twoRandChars(chars) + twoRandChars(CHARS) + twoRandChars(NUMS) + twoRandChars(SPEC);

        System.out.print(pass);
    }
}
```

[Check the demo](https://codidate.com/code/sandbox?s=f3j86mlavw)